# is there any way to declare operator[] for std::pair?

Tags: c++, stl

I wanted to declare operator[] function for std::pair,
so I wrote down these code:

```
template<typename T>
T& std::pair<T, T>::operator[](int x) {
    if (x == 0)
        return p.first;
    return p.second;
}
```

but I got compile error,so is there any way to declare operator[] function for std::pair?

Comment: Why not just use an array if you want that syntax?

Comment: @0x499602D2: the OP wants to be able to refer to the elements `p.first` and `p.second` of a pair `p` as `p[0]` and `p[1]`. Not unreasonable, I would say.

Comment: @TonyK: `pair` can contain two different types, so `operator[]` does not have any obvious return type in general. And if the types are the same, "why not use an array" is a good question. (Aside: If the indices are compile-time constants, `std::get` might do what OP wants.) The best response to this question is probably "what are you actually trying to do?"

Comment: em, I heard that `pair` we can use `get()` on pair so I think it is possible to declare `[]` for pair...until I saw the usage of `std::get()` I knew where I was wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`operator[]` can't be overloaded as non-member-function. And since you are not allowed to change `std::pair<>` there is no way to access a pairs `first` and `second` by index using an `operator[]`.